# method not allowed in flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

i have a form like this: when i post the details it should be able to store it in an excel sheet.

```
  <div class="for" align="middle">
    <form action="/models" method="POST">
      <label for="fname">Customer Name</label></br>
      <input type="text" id="Cname" name="Cname" placeholder="Your name.."></br>

      <label for="cname">Customer Email id</label></br>
      <input type="text" id="mailid" name="mailid" placeholder="Your  email id.."></br>

      <label for="cnumber">Customer Contact Number</label></br>
      <input type="text" id="cnumber" name="cnumber" placeholder="Your phone number.."></br>

      <label for="plan">When do you plan to buy ?</label></br>
      <select id="plan" name="plan">
        <option value="Immediate">Immediate</option>
        <option value="1-3 Months">1-3 Months</option>
        <option value="4-6 Months">4-6 Months</option>
      </select>
        </br>
      <label for="spn">Sales Person Name</label></br>
      <input type="text" id="spn" name="spn" placeholder="Sales-person name.."></br>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
```

and my flask code is this:

```
@app.route('/cc' ,methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def cc():
    if request.method=='POST':
        def data():
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(url_for('customer_info.xlsx'))
            sheet = wb.active
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('info')
            print('hey')
            sheet[A2]= request.form['Cname']
            sheet[A3]= request.form['mailid']
            print('hello')
            sheet[A3]= request.form['cnumber']
            sheet[A4]= request.form['plan']
            sheet[A5]= request.form['spn']
            wb.save('customer_info.xlsx')
    return render_template('cc.html')


@app.route('/models' )
def models():
    return render_template('models.html')
```

im not getting the excel sheet filled when i run this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is posting to `/models`

```
<form action="/models" method="POST">
```

but your `/models` route does not accept POST as a method, and doesn't interact with the Excel sheet.

```
@app.route('/models' )
def models():
    return render_template('models.html')
```

I think you want to POST to `/cc` instead of `/models`.

Also, in your `cc` route you are defining a function called `data` but not calling that function. You can change that route to:

```
@app.route('/cc' ,methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def cc():
    if request.method=='POST':
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(url_for('customer_info.xlsx'))
        sheet = wb.active
        sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('info')
        print('hey')
        sheet[A2]= request.form['Cname']
        sheet[A3]= request.form['mailid']
        print('hello')
        sheet[A3]= request.form['cnumber']
        sheet[A4]= request.form['plan']
        sheet[A5]= request.form['spn']
        wb.save('customer_info.xlsx')
    return render_template('cc.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can't see the 'hey' and 'hello' in the terminal. Your problem is that you define the "**data**" function but you don't execute it.

Change the cc route to this:

```
@app.route('/cc' ,methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def cc():
    if request.method=='POST':
        def data():
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(url_for('customer_info.xlsx'))
            sheet = wb.active
            sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('info')
            print('hey')
            sheet[A2]= request.form['Cname']
            sheet[A3]= request.form['mailid']
            print('hello')
            sheet[A3]= request.form['cnumber']
            sheet[A4]= request.form['plan']
            sheet[A5]= request.form['spn']
            wb.save('customer_info.xlsx')
        data()
    return render_template('cc.html')
```

Comment: I changes are done , but the entries for the excel sheet is not running .

Comment: Check teh answer by @MattHealy, i didn't see that you posted to the second route.